# Python. Did I understand the code correctly?

Tags: python

I have a little question. Does this piece of code means: "whenever an instance of the class MyThread created, initialize threading.Thread constructor and assign passed arguments to variables inside MyThread class". Essentially what this class does is it creates an instance of threading.Thread class AND adds a little bit of custom functionality, such as new variables. Right?

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, func, args, name=''):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
```

If I am correct, this piece of code

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
          def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

simply creates an instance of threading.Thread class and in fact the same can be done by simply putting `a = threading.Thread()`. Correct?

Comment: `MyThread` is a subclass of `threading.Thread`. It's not making another instance, it's just calling the constructor of the parent class.

Comment: But doesn't calling the constructor mean actually creating an instance?

Comment: No, because it's passing `self`, so it initializes the instance that we're in the process of initializing.

Comment: There can be situations when instance is created without calling an constructor - usually when deserializing (unpickling) a serialized instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
class MyCls(BaseCls):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseCls.__init__(self)
```

is the same as

```
class MyCls(BaseCls):
    pass # constructor not overriden
```

`BaseCls` constructor will be called in both cases when creating `MyCls` objects.

`MyCls` (when "empty") and `BaseCls` are still different things, there will be some differences if for example `BaseCls` uses `__slots__`.

Answer (score 0):

That part of the code is not creating an instance of `threading.Thread`. The code is declaring a class that is a subclass (or specialization) of `threading.Thread()`, that is, when you make an instance of `MyThread` it will be a `threading.Thread` itself. `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` is just initializing the class instance as a `threading.Thread` by calling that class constructor, that is commonly done with `super(MyThread, self).__init__()` when using new style classes.

Doing `a = threading.Thread()` is just creating an instance of the `Thread` class, nothing more.